# Cesar Coding question using .get method for dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a homework where it's asking me to fill out the blanks in the below function using .get method for dicts. The problem I am having is that when I try to use cipher.get() method, I don't know what to pass through the method for the key:value pairs. Bascially I want the .get method to return the encrypted letter if it is found in the dict, and return the original character if it is not found in the dict.

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cipher = {letters[i]: letters[(i-3) % len(letters)] for i in range(len(letters))}



def transform_message(message, cipher):
    tmsg = ''
    for c in message:
        tmsg = tmsg + ___
    return tmsg
```

Comment: `tmsg = tmsg + cipher.get(c)`. Take the current character `c`, look up the corresponding value for that key in `cipher`.

Comment: @PaulM. You need to cast `cipher.get(c)` as `string`

Comment: @Cardstdani: It's already a `str` (`str` are collections of length 1 `str`s). You just want `cipher.get(c, c)` so things that aren't in the `dict` (non-alphabetic) map to themselves.

Comment: no, if I don't add str(cipher.get(c,c)) it throws me a TypeError

Comment: @nomoresky: Yeah, that's because some of what's in there isn't mapped, and `get` with only one argument is returning `None`. That's why I suggest `cipher.get(c, c)`; it returns `c` when the key is missing, rather than `None`, and `c` is a `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `.get()` function, you need to pass `c` as an argument in order to get the ciphered letter from `c` like that:

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cipher = {letters[i]: letters[(i-3) % len(letters)] for i in range(len(letters))}



def transform_message(message, cipher):
    tmsg = ''
    for c in message:
        tmsg += cipher.get(c,c)
    return tmsg
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. However, when I try to do the function call and pass through transform_message(test, c), it says c is not defined?

Comment: You need to execute `transform_message(test, cipher)` not `transform_message(test, c)`

Comment: @nomoresky With `c` I was referring to the `c` variable inside the function

Comment: Tried to execute (test,cipher) and it says "must be str, not NoneType"

Comment: You may have a problem with your input types, try casting your message as `string`

Comment: The message is already in string format, the TypeError is pointing to the tmsg + cipher.get(c) line.

Comment: @nomoresky You're right, I have already edited the answer and `casted cipher.get()` as `string`

Comment: new problem: I want the .get method to return the letter if it is found in the original string, and if it is a space or a comma, I want to it return the space or comma. But now it is returning "None" instead of spaces and commas.

Comment: @nomoresky Please open a new Question or edit your current question in order to avoid problem statements in the comments